# Spring Security: GlobalMethodSecurity not calling custom AccessDecisionManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I seem to be having a interesting issue where the  GlobalMethodSecurity wont call the correct AccessDecisionManager:

I have set the AccessDecisionManager in the **application-context.xml:**

```
<global-method-security  access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager2"/>
```

and have also defined the bean for the **CustomAccessDecisionManager:**

```
@Bean
public AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager2() {
        List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> decisionVoters = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, AccessDecisionVoter> beans = context.getBeansOfType(AccessDecisionVoter.class);
        CustomAccessDecisionVoter customAccessDecisionVoter = new CustomAccessDecisionVoter();
        decisionVoters.add(customAccessDecisionVoter);

        AffirmativeBased affirmativeBased = new AffirmativeBased(decisionVoters);

        return affirmativeBased;
}
```

Code for the **customAccessDecisionVoter:**

```
@Service
public class CustomAccessDecisionVoter extends AuthenticatedVoter{


    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    public int vote(Authentication authentication, FilterInvocation fi,
            Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes) {


        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(ConfigAttribute attribute) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(attribute.toString());
        return true;
    }
}
```

it seems to be calling its default **AccessDecisionManager:**

```
    DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-10] (OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.java:85) - Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-10] (AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:218) - Secure object: ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public java.lang.String com.DPP.V2.GUIController.PageDispatcher.test(); target is of class [com.DPP.V2.GUIController.PageDispatcher]; Attributes: [[authorize: 'hasAuthority('ROLE_read_only')', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']]
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-10] (AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:347) - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@a9768c42: Principal: com.DPP.V2.sessions.SessionUser@3b40b2f: Username: ADMIN; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: e17bd41a-0726-47e0-a024-053a0d5d0f6c_grant_sensitive,e17bd41a-0726-47e0-a024-053a0d5d0f6c_test,e17bd41a-0726-47e0-a024-053a0d5d0f6c_write_all; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@380f4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 6F802321EC029F9588F0D8C0582AD97B; Granted Authorities: e17bd41a-0726-47e0-a024-053a0d5d0f6c_grant_sensitive, e17bd41a-0726-47e0-a024-053a0d5d0f6c_test, e17bd41a-0726-47e0-a024-053a0d5d0f6c_write_all
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-10] (AffirmativeBased.java:65) - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter@13882b00, returned: -1
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-10] (AffirmativeBased.java:65) - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@10ced22f, returned: 0
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-10] (AffirmativeBased.java:65) - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@63943f99, return
```

the reason i need to have a custom voter is because the roles are prefixed with a id that changes, and the standard voters don't support this.

any help would be much appreciated :)